# Post only one specific category on the index page of my wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress, indexing, blogs, categories

I have a category named "Highlights".  I would like the main-index page to only show the "Highlights" category.

I created a loop-index.php file.  How do I change it to only show one category named "Highlights"?

Thank you.

Here is the code of my index-loop.php:

```
<?php /* If there are no posts to display, such as an empty archive page */ ?>
<?php if ( ! have_posts() ) : ?>

<h1>
<?php _e( 'Not Found', 'discover' ); ?>
</h1>
<p>
<?php _e( 'Apologies, but no results were found for the requested archive. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.', 'discover' ); ?>
</p>
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<!--loop starts here-->

<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<div class="post-head">
<h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'discover' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark">
<?php if ( get_the_title() == '' ) { _e( '(No title)', 'discover' ); } else { the_title(); } ?>
</a></h1>
</div>
<!--post-heading end-->

<div class="meta-data">
<?php discover_posted_on(); ?>
in
<?php the_category(', '); ?>
|
<?php comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave a comment', 'discover' ), __( '1 Comment', 'discover' ), __( '% Comments', 'discover' ) ); ?>
</div>
<!--meta data end-->

<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="post-entry">
<?php if ( is_archive() || is_search() ) :  ?>
<?php the_content( __( '<span class="read-more">Read More</span>', 'discover' ) ); ?>
<div class="clear"></div>
<?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '' . __( 'Pages:', 'discover' ), 'after' => '' ) ); ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail(array(620,240), array("class" => "alignleft post_thumbnail")); } ?>
<?php the_content( __( '<span class="read-more">Read More</span>', 'discover' ) ); ?>
<div class="clear"></div>
<?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '' . __( 'Pages:', 'discover' ), 'after' => '' ) ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<!--clear float-->
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<!--post-entry end-->

<?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
</div>
<!--post end-->

<?php endwhile; // End the loop. Whew. ?>

<!--pagination-->

<div class="navigation">
<div class="alignleft">
<?php next_posts_link( __( '&larr; Older posts', 'discover' ) ); ?>
</div>
<div class="alignright">
<?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts &rarr;', 'discover' ) ); ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add specific query in your page

This is sample query code

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'category_name' => 'Highlights',
  'orderby' => 'post_date',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => 5,
  'caller_get_posts'=> 1
);
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) { 
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?> 
    <?php the_title(); ?>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <?php endwhile;
    } else { ?>
    <p>There is no post in this category</p>
    <?php
    }
    wp_reset_query();
} 
?>
```

I hope you find your solution here. If you have any question, then ask me on this website abdul.thinkbeyoundwindow.com